# AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.billing' has no attribute 'Client'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, sdk

AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.billing' has no attribute 'Client'

i got this error how to solve this

i need response of billing data in my google cloud project.i using this method but iam getting error. how to solve this error